# How to install nginx and install the configuration files too

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt

I've just completely uninstalled nginx 1.0.6 from my server (Ubuntu 11.04) using

```
apt-get remove nginx 
rm -rf /etc/nginx/
rm -rf /usr/sbin/nginx
rm /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz
apt-get remove nginx*
```

Now I want to install it again, however when starting nginx, I get errors such as:

> Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Then I placed my own conf file, then I get a new error:

> Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/mime.types" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:12

Now it seems that `apt-get install nginx` doesn't install it completely, I cleared the apt-get cache, doesn't seem to help. How can I get a *full* installation of nginx using apt-get?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Run `apt-get remove --purge nginx nginx-full nginx-common` first, and then `apt-get install nginx` and see if it works.

Comment: I get this: `Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/mime.types" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:12
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: Try `apt-get install nginx-extras` and restart nginx.

Comment: Hmmm, I still get the same error above.

Comment: What is the output of `locate mime.types`? (run `sudo updatedb` first). Did the `apt-get install nginx-extras` do anything? Maybe you should try the commands on my initial answer, for the `nginx-extras` package too.

Comment: I get this: `/etc/mime.types
/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/examples/apache2/mime.types.gz
/usr/share/usermin/mime.types
/usr/share/webmin/mime.types`

Comment: Nice :) So just do a `cp /etc/mime.types /etc/nginx/mime.types` and restart.

Comment: I get this: `Restarting nginx: [emerg]: unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:822`

Comment: I've done it myself, thanks for the help you tried. I will post my answer in 6 hours (SF doesn't let me post in 6 hours).

Comment: After 2 hours this answer help me reinstall manually removed nginx. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

first

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss --reinstall install nginx-common
```

then test

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nginx
```

If you are not prompted to prove successful uninstall

```
 which nginx
```

Answer (score 2):

You first of all want to make sure that the older nginx is uninstalled completely together with its conf files.

```
 sudo service nginx stop
 sudo apt-get --purge autoremove nginx     
 sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx
 sudo rm /usr/sbin/nginx
```

Then install nginx. The nginx-extras comes in handy when you want to check your conf files for errors

```
 sudo apt-get install nginx nginx-extras
```

Then check whether your conf files are okay with the command;

```
 sudo nginx -t
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it by copying the configuration files from `/opt/` into `/etc/`:

```
cp /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
cp /opt/nginx/conf/mime.types /etc/nginx/
```